# Even though the Google Sites API creates a site, we cannot still access the site

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-sites

I m using Google Sites API in my python code deployed over Google App Engine.
I have came across a problem: Google Sites API allows to create a site, add users to site(access permission),etc.., however we get status:200 form the API that site is being created and same for adding users to the Google Site, but when i go to sites.google.com to access that site it still says 'Creating your site'

I can see a site locked in wait state for almost a week. We don't have any specific steps to reproduce it, this has random appearances.

Please suggest what is the correct solution or if there is no perfect solution than suggest a workaround for the same.

Comment: Are you tring to forward a custom_domain.com to an application in AppEngine?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to reach Google API's developers to tell them about this bug, they might not be aware of it.